# Can raman be used to know the number of layers other than graphene?

Tags: crystals, x-ray-crystallography, raman-spectroscopy, braggs-law

I came across some paper where the number of layers of Graphene have been investigated by Raman spectroscopy. I found simulation websites https://instanano.com/characterization/calculator/raman/graphene-layers/
,but unfortunately I did not understand the principle.

1. Would any one propose an easy source online, and explain briefly about the principle of number of layer calculation in Raman Spectroscopy? How to do it from the spectra?
2. Can this be done to other materials other than Graphene? I have not found a source about it.
   How do I confirm the method applicability to other layered materials. What kind of other methods do I have to confirm with?